# MySQL insert skipped IDs

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has two columns, `id` and `value`.
`id`(`auto_increment primary key`)
`value`(`varchar 255`)

```
insert into table columns(`id`,`value`)VALUES(,'something1');
insert into table columns(`id`,`value`)VALUES(,'something2');
```

output

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     value     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | something1    |
|  2 | something2    |
+----+---------------+
```

Now Inserting one value again

```
insert into table columns(`id`,`value`)VALUES(8,'something8');
```

Updated Table

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     value     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | something1    |
|  2 | something2    |
|  8 | something8    |
+----+---------------+
```

Now I am inserting one value again

```
insert into table columns(`id`,`value`)VALUES(,'something');
```

**Final Output**

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     value     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | something1    |
|  2 | something2    |
|  8 | something8    |
|  9 | something     |
+----+---------------+
```

**But I want the final output like this**

```
+----+---------------+
| id |     value     |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | something1    |
|  2 | something2    |
|  8 | something8    |
|  3 | something     |
+----+---------------+
```

Now `id` is `3` and further insertion will create `id` `4,5,6,7,9` and so on.

Is there any way to get achieve this ?

Comment: That is not how auto_increment work. You should not insert the value if the column is an auto_increment

Comment: It is not possible with auto increment you have to code differently. Because auto increment will add last digit + 1 .

Comment: is there any proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you **want** to achieve that? Why not let the database decide that for you?

Answer (score -1):

I know it is old post but mybie it will help someone :)

I am afraid it cannot be done automatically, however, I solved it to my client, maybe some of you could find it useful:

```
DECLARE FirstEmptyId int;

SELECT l.id +1 AS 
START 
FROM TableName AS l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableName AS r ON l.id +1 = r.id 
WHERE r.id IS NULL 
LIMIT 1 INTO FirstEmptyId;

Insert Into TableName (Id..) Values (FirstEmptyId...)
```

STILL, YOU HAVE TO MIND THAT IT IS NOT ADVISABLE TO INSERT ID VALUE OTHER WAY THAN BY AUTOINCREMENT IT AND THERE IS A REASON FOR THAT :) 

Consider creating the second column just for performance purposes.

Good luck fellow coders!

Comment: That does not look good - what if two requests happen at the same time, such that both request the same `FirstEmptyId`?

Comment: as I said it is not advisable. In small projects, you can use it in a stored procedure and lock table, but in bigger systems, as you said, it will cause problems.