# node mysql skip some id's after an insert(constraint) error

Tags: mysql, node.js

Using mysql with node and a weird thing is going on, never had that problem with PHP.

No transaction, just the default connection

found this : [MySQL insert skipped IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309661/mysql-insert-skipped-ids) no anwsers.

db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const Config =  {
  host: "XXXXX",
  port: XXXX,
  user: "root",
  password: "XXXXX",
  database: "XXXX",
  dateStrings: true,  
}

var connection = mysql.createConnection(Config);

connection.connect((ConnectionError) => {

    if (ConnectionError) throw ConnectionError;


    if(Config.datasource.debug) {
      console.log('Connected to '+Config.database + ' database');
    }
});
module.exports = connection;
```

inser_user.js

```
function create(Parameters) {

  const Arguments = [
    Parameters.username,
    Parameters.email,
    Parameters.password,
    Parameters.status];

  // Prepare la requette d'insertion
  const sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO user ' +
    '(username, email, password, status) ' +
    'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';

  return new Promise((Resolve, Reject)=>{

    connection.query(sql_insert,Arguments, (Error,Result)=>{
      if(Error) {
        return Reject(Error);
      }
      return Resolve(NewUser);
    });
  });
}
```

```
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| id    | username    | created_at          |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| 10039 | abcdefj     | 2020-10-19 13:28:41 | 
| 10040 | abcdefj1    | 2020-10-19 13:28:48 | err code 1062 x20 
| 10060 | abcdef      | 2020-10-19 13:44:25 | err code 1062 x8
| 10068 | abcdefz     | 2020-10-19 13:45:18 |
| 10069 | abcdefzx    | 2020-10-19 13:45:25 |
| 10070 | abcdefzxy   | 2020-10-19 13:45:26 |
| 10076 | abcdefzxv   | 2020-10-19 13:46:11 | err code 1062 x8
| 10079 | ab12        | 2020-10-19 16:03:17 |
| 10090 | ab123123123 | 2020-10-19 16:04:33 |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Every insert after a constraint error (1062 duplicate key) the id's are skipping.
If 20 constraint errors, 20 ids are skipped. Transaction by default? I'm missing
something? did the RTFM...

Comment: There's no answer at the other question because there's nothing you can do about it. It's just the way InnoDB works -- it reserves the auto increment values before checking for duplicates.

Comment: from mysql doc... 

“Lost” auto-increment values and sequence gaps

In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a transaction that generated auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled back. Such lost values are not reused. Thus, there may be gaps in the values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.

Thought it was just for transacation, but you're right! thank you!